# why Viewholder in the listview can't handle two textviews?

Tags: android

i get a fragment with listview inside another fragment,and the listview have a viewholder class like this:
`private   class ViewHolder{
          TextView rowText1;
          TextView rowText2;
    }`

and give the textview very simple task:

`holder.rowText1.setText(someString);
holder.rowText2.setText(someString);`

The Log give me a nullpointer error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
Attempt to invoke virtual method void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence) on a null object reference
```

But if i just give one view settext(any one), everything works fine:

```
holder.rowText1.setText(someString);
//holder.rowText2.setText(someString);
```

Any ideas why?

My viewholder code:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent,false);                          
            switch(type){
                case 1:
                    holder.rowText1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);                                              
                   break;
                case 2:
                    holder.rowText1  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    holder.rowText2 =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                    ImageView fileImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.typeImage);
                    fileImage.setImageDrawable(fileDrawable);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

Also,i dug a little bit ,find the problem seems to be in the view recycle stage,somehow when the system began to recycle the view ,with two views,it just doesnt work.

Comment: What is the problem? Looks like you did not finish writing this question before posting it.

Comment: sorry, this is my first post, i am trying to make the format right,now the question is finished.

Comment: So you've forgotten to init `rowText2` or it is init with null. Post the code where you set up the view holder.

Comment: I dont think so,using either  of the two is ok,just wrong using both.I post the view holder code

Comment: OK, after some looking,i find you are right ,it was due to the reason i put the settext code outside the switch clause,so when in case 1,rowtext2 still want to settext. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about changing your getView to this?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent,false)
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent,false);                          
            switch(type){
                case 1:
                    holder.rowText1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);                                              
                   break;
                case 2:
                    holder.rowText1  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    holder.rowText2 =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);                       
                    ImageView fileImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.typeImage);
                    fileImage.setImageDrawable(fileDrawable);
                    break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

This only does everything once and if the convertView isn't null it will return the already existing view.

For more info regarding adapters, view this: [How does the getView() method work when creating your own custom adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120119/how-does-the-getview-method-work-when-creating-your-own-custom-adapter)

Comment: Can you explain the logic? Isn't the point we should avoid calling inflate everytime?

Comment: You aren't inflating it every time but only when convertView is null. Howeveryou can try putting what i have outside the if (except the return) inside of it. Check updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your time, the problem is solved,i didn't initiate properly,i will post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

oK,so i solve the problem,as you can see in my original getview code,it didn'T include settext code.I put it after that,so adjust the code in this way(simply add the settext code):

```
switch(type){
                case 1:
              holder.rowText1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.rowText1.setText(someString);                                                                                                             
                    break;
                case 2:
                    holder.rowText1  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    holder.rowText2 =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);                       
                    holder.rowText1.setText(someString);
                   holder.rowText2.setText(someString);
                  ImageView fileImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.typeImage);
                fileImage.setImageDrawable(fileDrawable);
                    break;
            }
```

As you can see,because i only want to have one textview in case 1,when i put the settext code outside the switch clause,even in case 1,it still want to execute settext to rowtext2.it is a pretty dumb mistake,newbie spotted!!