# Android adapter

Tags: android, adapter

I have an `Adapter` with `ViewHolder`. Let's say I want to set data only once to the `ViewHoler` inside the `getView()` method, what's actually happened is, its set the data every time I'm scrolling the view.

How can I check if the `ViewHolder` was already init or not?

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
 convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
Deal deal = dealsArr.get(position);
holder.textView.setText(deal.getPrice);

// Here is my issue. how can I do it only once?
changePrice(deal, true);
}
```

Comment: You don't want to do that. The `AdapterView` (`ListView`, `GridView`, what have you) is reusing those `View`s for different positions. If you don't update the `View`s accordingly, your items aren't going to display correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asssume you already have the basic understanding of Android Adapters & working of `getCount()` & `getView()` [if not see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120119/how-does-the-getview-method-work-when-creating-your-own-custom-adapter)

---

Either adapter returns a null View or an Inflated View; findViewbyId(R.id.xmlID) is always executed;
ViewHolder is used to avoid frequent call and ensure the smooth scrolling of your listview.

[Excellent Explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501316/what-is-the-benefit-of-viewholder)

---

First spend sometime of understand **Listview's recycling mechanism!** 
The link I had shared also has a link to that.!

---

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //rest of the code goes here

}
```

focus on the parameters of this method, 
the `convertView`which is for recycling will be null initially because there is no recycling done yet 
so this part of the code will be executed;

```
if (convertView == null) {  //convertView is null when recycling isn't done
            holder = new ViewHolder();
 convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
```

so we initialize the view-holder & refer all our Views(Buttons, TextViews etc) using findview by id.

the next time `getView()` is called; it executes this part of the code;

```
else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

**I'd strongly recommend to first understand working of Android Adapters & List View Recyling Mechanism without using ViewHolders in your code. first you understand how & when the methods are invoked then use `ViewHolder`** for more optimization